# Sampling small set of indices from a very large set

Tags: sampling, uniform-distribution

I have a set containing 100 millions of indices. 
In each iteration, I choose $k$ sub-samples from this set, and once I select the $k$-samples, I increase or decrease the probability for the selected subsamples marginally by $\epsilon$ depending on the performance I get using the corresponding index ($\epsilon$ is directly proportional to this performance). In my settings, $k$ is very small and takes values less than 50.

I notice that this sampling method will still result in very biased sampling and some of the indices will not be sampled. For example, if all the indices in the first 3 or 4 iterations gives me good performance, probability of the remaining indices getting sampled becomes very low.
Is there a better approach which will make sure that all the indices will be sampled with some certainty ?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an "explore/exploit tradeoff" problem. Specifically, you want to exploit the high-performing samples, while occasionally exploring unseen samples.

A very simple solution: each time you choose a sample, with probability $p$ choose a sample according to your weighting scheme above, and with probability $1-p$ choose an unseen sample. Eventually, you'll see all the samples (with arbitrarily high probability) if you run it long enough.

There are likely further optimizations depending on the problem setting.